# Modifying VBA JSON File

Tags: json, vba, excel, vbscript

I want to modify a JSON file in excel using vba.

So I have this JSON file

```
{
    "root": [{
        "STATUS_RESPONSE": {
            "STATUS": {
                "STATUS": {
                    "OWNER": "root",
                }
            },
            "REQ_ID": "00000",
            "RESULT": [{
                "USER": {
                    "BUSINESS_ID": "A",
                    "USER_NUMBER": "45",
                    "LANGUAGE": "F",
                }
            },
            {
                "USER_SESSION": {
                    "USER_ID": "0000001009",
                    "HELP_URL": "http://google.com",
                }
            },
            {
                "USER_ACCESS": {
                    "SERVICES_ROLE": "true",
                    "JOURNALLING": "true",

                }
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

I want to modify just the "BUSINESS_ID"

Then I can export to the same JSON file using this

```
   Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim rng As Range, items As New Collection, myitem As New Dictionary, i As Integer, cell As Variant, myfile As String
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim buss As String
Dim JsonTS As TextStream
Set rng = Range("A2")
Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("test.json", ForReading)
JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
JsonTS.Close
Set JSON = ParseJson(JsonText)
JSON("root")(1)("STATUS_RESPONSE")("RESULT")(1)("USER")("BUSINESS_ID") = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value
buss = JSON("root")(1)("STATUS_RESPONSE")("RESULT")(1)("USER")("BUSINESS_ID")
myfile = "test.json"
Open myfile For Output As #1
Write #1, buss
Close #1
End Sub
```

I can edit the cell and this would replace the JSON file but it takes away the whole structure from the JSON file above.

I get something similar to this like in the json file if I change the business id to C:

```
"C"
```

Is there a way that I can just modify the thing I need in the existing file without everything else disappearing

Comment: You should be exporting the whole `JSON` object, not just one part of it.  Did you delete your previous queston?

Comment: How would I do the whole JSON object

Comment: `Write #1, JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(JSON, Whitespace:=2)`   https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: ...wow mind blown, put it as the answer so I can reward you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be exporting the whole `JSON` object, not just one part of it.

```
Write #1, JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(JSON, Whitespace:=2)
```